# Red block being displayed behind my image link

Tags: html, image, css, hyperlink, navigation

I put a link in the image which leads back to the home page; however, I have my nav menu set up so they turn red with hovering and somehow it's making a red block behind my image when I hover over it. I'm using HTML5 and CSS3

HTML5

```
<header class ="main-header">
        <a href="index.html">
        <img src="Images/image.png" alt="image logo"></a>           

    <nav><ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="index/news/news.html">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="index/location/location.html">LOCATION</a></li>
    </ul></nav>     
</header>
```

CSS3

```
/* Define Hyperlink Info */


a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited{
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #C71F0E;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Defines navigation menu */

.main-header nav {
    background-color: #354175;
    height: 40px;
}

.main-header nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto;
}

.main-header nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.main-header nav li a:hover, .main-header nav li.active {
    background-color: #C71F0E;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.main-header nav ul li a {
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `a:link, a:visited` line, you'll notice that this targets **ALL** links, even your image link.

To do away with this, try giving your first link a class (like "logo"), and write specific styles for it **after** the `a:link, a:visited` line.